# How to draw fixed pixels images in custom material property with Cesium?

Tags: javascript, fragment-shader, cesiumjs

I need to draw images that sizes are fixed, i could get a **0~1** coordinate with `materialInput.st`, but i don't know how to get a **0~resolution** coordinate. So is there any built-in properties or other ways to reslove this?

And another problem is that when i zoom out to some levels, my material might stretch or wrap like in a mirror according to my camera's orientation, i have no idea of this situation.

The last one is about `materialInput.positionToEyeEC`, i can't understand this property very well. Could somebody talk about it in more detail or give some examples?

my custom material property code is below.

```
function SpotMaterialProperty(color) {
  this._definitionChanged = new Cesium.Event()
  this._color = undefined
  this._colorSubscription = undefined

  this._time = Date.now()

  this.color = Cesium.defaultValue(color, Cesium.Color.WHITE)
}

Object.defineProperties(SpotMaterialProperty.prototype, {
  isConstant: {
    get: function () {
      return false
    }
  },
  definitionChanged: {
    get: function () {
      return this._definitionChanged
    }
  },
  color: Cesium.createPropertyDescriptor('color')
})

SpotMaterialProperty.prototype.getType = function () {
  return 'Spot'
}

SpotMaterialProperty.prototype.getValue = function (time, result) {
  if (!Cesium.defined(result)) {
    result = {}
  }
  result.color = Cesium.Property.getValueOrUndefined(this._color, time)
  result.time = (Date.now() - this._time) / 1000

  return result
}

SpotMaterialProperty.prototype.equals = function (other) {
  return (
    this === other || //
    (other instanceof SpotMaterialProperty && Cesium.Property.equals(this._color, other._color))
  )
}

Cesium.Material.SpotMaterialSource = `uniform float time;
uniform vec4 color;

czm_material czm_getMaterial (czm_materialInput materialInput) {
  czm_material material = czm_getDefaultMaterial(materialInput);
  vec2 coord = materialInput.st.xy;

  float size = 300.;
  coord *= size;

  vec4 f = color;
  vec4 bg = vec4(f.rgb, f.a * .2);
  
  float x = mod(floor(coord.x + time * .3), 2.);
  float y = mod(floor(coord.y + time * .3), 2.);

  f.a *= x * y * .5;
  f += bg;

  material.diffuse = f.rgb;
  material.emission = f.rgb;
  material.alpha = f.a;

  return material;
}`

Cesium.Material.SpotType = 'Spot'
Cesium.SpotMaterialProperty = SpotMaterialProperty

Cesium.Material._materialCache.addMaterial(Cesium.Material.SpotType, {
  fabric: {
    type: Cesium.Material.SpotType,
    uniforms: {
      color: Cesium.Color.WHITE,
      time: 0
    },
    source: Cesium.Material.SpotMaterialSource
  },
  translucent: function (material) {
    return material.uniforms.color.alpha < 1.0
  }
})
```

Thanks for help.

----- 2021-9-3 updated -----
[image]

[image]

This is another material and the image in two level the second is normal and the first is obviously out of shape.

Answer (score 0):

The `Property` version, like all Cesium Entity Properties, is meant to describe how the definition of something changes over time when Cesium animates. For example, a `MaterialProperty` could indicate a solid color during one time interval, and a striped material during a separate time interval. The actual underlying `Material` may be destroyed and a replacement one created during animation as a result of this.

This should be fixed in the upcoming release (1.16) You can use this code to make a translucent image:

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer');
viewer.entities.add({
    rectangle: {
        coordinates: Cesium.Rectangle.fromDegrees(-125,30,-110,40),
        material: new Cesium.ImageMaterialProperty({
            image: '../images/Cesium_Logo_Color.jpg',
            alpha: 0.5
        }),
    }
});
```

Comment: It's helpful, but not for my questions, **don't just CV plz** →_→.